# Why !includedir means import file?

Tags: linux, bash, mariadb

```
cat  /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf 
# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory  
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/                                                                                                                                               
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

The comment means that `!includedir` can import files which near it.
Why `!includedir` means that ? There is no command `includedir` in bash!Does `!` means execute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!includedir` is not a Bash command. Remember that you are looking at a configuration file from MariaDB. This file is not even supposed to be interpreted by Bash, but will be read by MariaDB when it starts up.

If you read the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#option-file-syntax), you'll see that it's unique to MariaDB's option file syntax:

> The `!includedir` directive can be used to include all .cnf files (and potentially .ini files) in a given directory. The option files within the directory are read in alphabetical order.

Comment: The `!` sign is really misleading, I though `!` means "not"...